# Can't FTP files to my hosted server. Writes are being blocked

Tags: ftp, deployment

I just installed vsftpd on my Ubuntu (Lucid) server and followed the [config recommendations](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/ftp-server.html). I made sure that "Write_enable=YES".

I'm able to connect via FTP, but when I try to "mput" a local file into /var/www, I get the following error:

"553 Could not create file."

I believe writing files to the /var/www directory requires sudo access, but when I tried "sudo mput", I got an error msg saying that this was not a valid command.

When I use FireFTP, my writes are still being blocked.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `sudo mput` on your client isn't going to make a bit of difference in your ability to write files on the server, as that command only escalates your permissions on the client machine. Also, setting `Write_enable=YES` in the vsftpd config is only going to enable the *possibility* of writing to the ftp server. You need to check the permissions on `/var/www` itself to see if your user has write access.

Run `$ ls -la /var/www`, edit your question and post the output.

Also, what's the username you're using with FTP and what groups is that user in?

Comment: I got it working. You're right - I just needed to add write permissions (chmod) for me and the group. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[this might help](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/vsftpd-error-553-could-not-create-file-390569/), optionally you can use sftp with filezilla to write to the directory.